# Deploy iOs app with iTunes without registration

Tags: ios, deployment, ipa, ad-hoc-distribution, in-house-distribution

I have just developed our new iOs app and deployed it through iTunes to my iPhone. 
I don't want to use the app store because it's an internal app. I would like to be able to send a link to the ipa and for someone to be able to download it and install it through iTunes. Is that possible?

The only solution I have came across so far is registering the receiver iPhones in my provisioning and use the ad-hoc deployment process. 
We used to have an ipa that would install as described on any iPhone without any kind of registration.

I am bit confused between ad-hoc distribution and in-house distribution...

Would paying €299 for an organization account solve that?

Thanks! 
Victor

Answer (score 0):

- Yes, you will need to shell out those €299 if you ever wanna get into *serious* app development.
- Yes, you are correct, *registering the receiver iPhones in my provisioning and use the ad-hoc deployment process* can be done easily but will start to wear you out once the number of test devices start to go up.
- This [Apple Doc](http://help.apple.com/deployment/ios/#/apda0e3426d7) is the *perfect* guide to get you started with setting up an internal distribution host service.